# breeze entity type has recursive definition

Tags: breeze

the following code will often run out of stack space because the type Entity has a property named EntityAspect, which has a property named Entity of type Entity which points to the owning Entity.  This recursive definition causes several tools to fail or run incredibly slow, but most notably, knockout.  Can anything be done to address this?

```
var custType = _this.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");
var cust1 = custType.createEntity();
var js = ko.toJS(cust1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this yet but I think you can do this

```
var js = ko.mapping.toJS(cust1, {
    ignore: ['entityAspect']
});
```

Comment: Ignoring entityAspect may not suffice - I'm afraid there are other recursive loops. I gave up on calling toJS(), but it would be nice to have it as an option in debugging scenarios.

Comment: To compound this issue I think something else is going on under the covers when you use toJS on it because it is EXTREMELY slow.  I switched over and wrote a custom serializer that is much faster but it's ugly at the moment.  When I clean it up I will do a pull request on GitHub to add it in.

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to ignore both entityAspect and entityType (snippet from custom datasource kendo datasource):

```
            this.entityManager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (xhr) {
                if (self.autoMapToJS) { // Breeze entities contain recursive properties (ugh!) - eliminate those
                    payload.data = ko.mapping.toJS(xhr.results, {
                        ignore: ['entityAspect', 'entityType']
                    });
                } else {
                    payload.data = xhr.results;
                }
                if (self.inlineCount) {
                    payload.total = xhr.inlineCount;
                }
                options.success(payload); // notify the DataSource that the operation is complete
            })
            .fail(function (rejected) {
                payload.error = rejected;
            })
            .done(); // terminate chain of promises
    }
```

In particular, trying to use with grids (wijmo & kendo), I was forced to map breeze data or enjoy stackoverflows as those controls would iterate through the properties.

Comment: Maybe you should add to your ignore-list: "complexType", "complexAspect", "_$typeName", "_$interceptor"